# Template Engine for Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, template-engine

I want to generate a html in my windows store app(targets Windows 8.1).
(And then it will be displayed by webView.NavigateToString or saved as html file.)

So I want to use some Template Engine such as RazorEngine.
But RazorEngine(on nuget) is not supported WinRT.
I also tried to `Install-Package` "NVelocity", "Antlr4.StringTemplate", and "DotLiquid" .
All of them not supported WinRT.

Is there any template engine library for windows store app?